# How do I transform backend data with async fields in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, dto

In my angular application, I have to transform some data from backend API. The problem is that some fields need to be assigned with data from the server either.

For example, I have a client (it's a simplified example):

```
{
  id: 1122,
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe',
  countryId: 12
}
```

There is a country ID. I want to get country name from the server by the ID.

I have used asynchronous angular pipes in template that returns Observable with country name string:

```
<h3>{{ client.countryId | countryAsyncPipe | async}}</h3>
```

But I need data not only in the templates.

So, how do I resolve this kind of a problem?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**:

I'm sorry, I haven't provided enough information in the question. I will try to explain what I mean with some hypothetic example.

First of all, I.ve forgot to say that I'm trying to create DTO. I've got an API Service, for instance, ClientHttpService:

```
@Service()
class ClientHttpService extends Http {

  findAll(): Observable<Array<Client>> {
    return this.get(this.url).pipe(
        map(client => clientSerializer.fromJsonFactory(client))
      );
  }
}
```

I receive JSON clients and create instances of ClientModel (not necessary, it may be a literal object) with serializer service:

```
class Client extends Model {
  id: number;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  countryName: string;

  constructor({ id, firstname, lastname, countryName }) {
    //...set object properties
  }
}

@Service()
class ClientSerializer implements Serializer {

  public fromJson(data: any): Client {
    return new Client({
      id: data.id,
      firstname: data.firstname,
      lastname: data.lastname,
      countryName: data.countryId // trouble
    });
  }

  public fromJsonFactory(data: Array<any>): Array<Client> {
    return data.map(client => this.fromJson(client));
  }
}
```

Well, here is a problem. I really don't understand how to provide the country name. Let's say, I've got CountryService:

```
@Service()
class CountryHttpService extends Http {

  findNameById(id: number): Observable<string> {
    return this.get(`countryUrl`).pipe(map(country => country.name));
  }
}
```

How could I correctly provide result into my Serializer if it returns Observable?

```
return new Client({
  //...
  countryName: countryService.findNameById(data.countryId) // Observable, not string
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `subscribe()` or `toPromise().then()` in order to get the desired data within your .ts file.
For example, let's say you have a CountryService with a method

```
getCountryName(countryId: number): Observable<string> {
   return this.http.get<string>(your endpoint);
}
```

In the component that you want to fetch the countryName you should inject your service and:

```
this.countryService .getCountryName(countryId).toPromise().then( (countryName: string) => {
   // transform your data here
});
```

or replace `toPromise().then()` with `subscribe()`.

**UPDATE**:

```
 public fromJson(data: any): Client {
    this.countryService.findNameById(data.countryId).subscribe((countryName: string) => {
        return new Client({
           id: data.id,
           firstname: data.firstname,
           lastname: data.lastname,
           countryName: countryName
        });
    });
   return null;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I've marked your answer as correct. But it's not the answer I've looked for, sorry. I add some explanations if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Http CountryService with a method findById(id:number), inject this service in your component.

Comment: I am afraid that's not what has been asked. I think Alfap don't know how to get value from Observable in typescript. (he will need something like switchmap)...